# android - unregistering a broadcast receiver in service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a `broadcastReceiver` in my service, and I register it in `onCreate()`.

When app is moved to background, service is brought to the foregound and showing an ongoing notification.

Here is the thing - I know that the service `onDestory` method is **not guaranteed** to be called, and I noticed that it is not called when app is removed from open apps list (swapped away),  and service is in foreground.

So - I have another class which takes care of doing some last-minute stuff in case the `onDestroy` isn't called  - some `SharedPreferences` actions for example.

**My question is -** I call `unregisterReceiver` in `onDestory`, but in case `onDestory` won't be called, is the receiver still registered? should I worry about unregistering it in the other class which takes care of the `SharedPreferences` stuff? or its already unregistered by itself?